# How to change UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, iphonecoredatarecipes

I'm using `iPhoneCoreDataRecipes` sample as as base code for my project and there is one thing that I was not able to modify. Also, I'm not quite sure if it is even possible.

I would like to modify the table that displays recipes (the first one). Right now the table gets the data from `recipeListController`and by default it covers the whole screen. I would like to change that. I still want to build a table with recipes data but I'm planning to shrink the table and modify its look.
I guess table view controller is  created in the `mainWindow.xib`.
Normally when I'm creating tables, I'm inserting them into `UIViewController` in the interface builder and then I use  `UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>` in my class.
Here are the bits that I think I need to modify:

```
   @interface RecipeListTableViewController : UITableViewController <RecipeAddDelegate,   NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> {
```

to something like this:

```
    @interface RecipeListTableViewController : UIViewController <RecipeAddDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
```

and then after creating `UIView` Controller in `MainWindow.xib` I think I need to hook it up with `recipeListController`. Inside of this `UIView`, I want to have a custom table, which then should use recipe data. Unfortunately I get errors...

I would appreciate any suggestions. Here is the project that I used:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: What kind of errors do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion : create a uiview below the table view, then put the table view as a subview of that view, and then you can manage its size as being not full screen. The underlying view is mapped to the RecipeListTableViewController.view outlet, you probably need to create another one for the table view (just to call [tableView reloadData] for example). The delegate and data source of the table view point as well to RecipeListTableViewController. By experience this will work.

Comment: Yes. It worked. Sorry if my question was a bit confusing and thanks for your help.